# Getting "No such file or directory" error when using shell script even though directory successfully moved to target

Tags: linux, file, directory, find, mv

I wrote a script to move directories (not files) from a source directory to a target directory, but I am getting the following error even though the move itself is successful:

`find: '/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/cdmp_dir_30days': No such file or directory`

##### Script output

```
find /u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/ -name 'cdmp*' -mtime +7 -exec mv '{}' /home/oracle/dba/backup/logs/l01nsvl-dtdao01/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace ';'

find: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/cdmp_dir_30days': No such file or directory

find: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/cdmp_dir_180days': No such file or directory

find: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/cdmp_dir_7days': No such file or directory
```

##### Manual execution output

```
[oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace]$ ls -ltr $SOURCE

total 3660

drwxr-----. 2 oracle oinstall    4096 Mar 12  2019 cdmp_dir_180days/

drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall   20480 Aug 29 05:17 cdmp_dir_30days/

drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall   36864 Sep 18 13:22 cdmp_dir_7days/

-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 3664330 Sep 27 10:52 alert_old.log

-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall    2899 Sep 28 14:52 alert_+ASM1.log

-rwx------. 1 oracle oinstall     230 Sep 28 15:11 b*

-rwx------. 1 oracle oinstall     395 Sep 28 15:25 a*

[oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace]$ ls -ltr $TARGET

total 0

[oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace]$ find /u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/ -name 'cdmp*' -mtime +7 -exec mv '{}' /home/oracle/dba/backup/logs/l01nsvl-dtdao01/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace ';'

find: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/cdmp_dir_30days': No such file or directory

find: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/cdmp_dir_180days': No such file or directory

find: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/cdmp_dir_7days': No such file or directory

[oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace]$ ls -ltr $SOURCE

total 3600

-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 3664330 Sep 27 10:52 alert_old.log

-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall    2899 Sep 28 14:52 alert_+ASM1.log

-rwx------. 1 oracle oinstall     230 Sep 28 15:11 b*

-rwx------. 1 oracle oinstall     395 Sep 28 15:25 a*

[oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace]$ ls -ltr $TARGET

total 88

drwxr-----. 2 oracle oinstall   256 Mar 12  2019 cdmp_dir_180days/

drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall 36864 Aug 29 05:17 cdmp_dir_30days/

drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall 45056 Sep 18 13:22 cdmp_dir_7days/
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue with the name of the files, like a non printable character, could you please share the code format output from the following command so we can confirm please?

```
find /u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/ -name 'cdmp*' -mtime +7 | od -c
```

I would also suggest to add the `-type d` flag to only filter directories.

Comment: [oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace]$ asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace ';'|od -c                <
0000000

Comment: I also added -type d but it dint help

Comment: I think your output is not correct, what is all of this:
`[oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace]$ asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace ';'|od -c < 0000000 –`

Comment: I tried in different directory but got the same results

Comment: [oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/home/oracle/dba/work/sali]$ ls -ltr
total 84
drwxr-----. 2 oracle oinstall  4096 Mar 12  2019 cdmp_01/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall 32768 Aug 29 05:17 dir_30days.ali/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall 40960 Sep 18 13:22 dir_7days.ali/
-rwx------. 1 oracle oinstall  1447 Sep 23 15:31 a*
-rwx------. 1 oracle oinstall  3044 Sep 28 15:44 lpl_del_ora_osfiles.ksh*
[oracle@l01nsvl-dtdao01:+ASM1:/home/oracle/dba/work/sali]$ find . -name cdmp* -mtime +7 -exec mv '{}' /tmp \;
find: `./cdmp_01': No such file or directory

Comment: Please run the following command, this will only search for files and show the output in `od` so we can confirm there aren't non printable characters, this will not harm anything but give us clarification. 
`find /u01/app/oracle/diag/asm/+asm/+ASM1/trace/ -name 'cdmp*' -mtime +7 | od -c`